# MySQL query to group by age, 3 months, 6 months, 9 months and 12 months

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+------+------------+ 
| cost | date       |
+------+------------+ 
|   44 | 2015-04-30 | 
|   39 | 2015-04-31 | 
|   18 | 2015-04-01 | 
|   71 | 2015-01-02 | 
|   69 | 2014-12-03 | 
|   62 | 2014-12-04 | 
|   89 | 2014-08-05 | 
|   72 | 2014-08-06 | 
|   46 | 2014-05-07 | 
|   23 | 2014-05-08 |
+------+------------+
```

From the table above, I would like to write a query that separates the total cost in 3 months, 6 months 9 months and 1 year ago from now.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post what you've tried.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight it is a mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `case` statement in the `group by`:

```
select (case when date >= date_sub(now(), interval 3 month) then '3month'
             when date >= date_sub(now(), interval 6 month) then '6month'
             when date >= date_sub(now(), interval 9 month) then '9month'
             when date >= date_sub(now(), interval 12 month) then '12month'
        end) as grp, sum(cost) as sumcost
from table t
where date >= date_sub(now(), interval 12 month)
group by grp;
```